# Redirect Failed to many Redirects - WWW in URL

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a Website that when i type [www.mywebsite.co.uk](http://www.mywebsite.co.uk) i get an error showing to many redirects but if i just use mywebsite.co.uk it routes fine.

below is my .htaccess and im using Yii2 Advanced App

Can anyone offer any help with this?

```
RewriteEngine on

# hide files and folders
RedirectMatch 404 /_protected
RedirectMatch 404 /\.git
RedirectMatch 404 /composer\.
RedirectMatch 404 /.bowerrc

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? It should not be too hard to remove stuff from that configuration until the problem is triggered

Comment: H Nico, I have reviewed these two lines as i believe these are the ones that control the redirect. but didn't seem to be able to solve it but did get to working out it was the "www" that was causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many requests invariably means you are creating a loop via the rules in your .htaccess so the page keeps reloading or is unable to load so it reloads and eventually times out. This is how I control URL access;

```
 # Start rewrite rules
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 # HTTPS on & remove www prefix
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ https://mywebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

 # Remove html extension
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
 RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

 # Remove php extension
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
 RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

 # 301 redirect index to https
 Redirect 301 /index https://mywebsite.com
```

Comment: thank you! 

I add the "[or] and www" line and it now redirects removing the www so works perfect

Comment: Nice 1 :) Glad I could help.